# onLocationChanged only called once, not refreshing

Tags: android, android-location

I made a little gps app for some reason onLocationChanged not refreshing, it only run once, on app start.

Here is my code:

```
public BackgroundLocationService() {
        super("myintentservice");

        locManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        Criteria crt = new Criteria();
        crt.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
        String bestProvider = locManager.getBestProvider(crt, true);

        boolean gps_enabled;
        boolean network_enabled;
        boolean best_enabled;

        gps_enabled = locManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        network_enabled = locManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
        best_enabled = locManager.isProviderEnabled(bestProvider);


        if (best_enabled) {
            locManager.requestLocationUpdates(bestProvider, 15000, 20, locListener);
            Log.i(TAG, "Best enabled: " + bestProvider);
        } else {
            Log.i("Location Provider: ", "best not enabled: " + bestProvider);
            if (gps_enabled) {
                locManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locListener);
                Log.i(TAG, "gps enabled!");
            }
            if (network_enabled) {
                locManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locListener);
                Log.i(TAG, "network enabled!");
            }
        }

    }



    class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

            if (location != null) {

                //locManager.removeUpdates(locListener);
                longitude = Double.toString(location.getLongitude());
                latitude = Double.toString(location.getLatitude());

                Log.i(TAG,"Location has CHANGED!");
            }
        }
        public void onProviderDisabled(String arg) {}
        public void onProviderEnabled(String arg) {}
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}
    }
```

The "Location has CHANGED!" message only shows once with each app start.
Im in an office but i can move at least 5-10 meters away from my position and ALL the providers are enabled so it must be Ok, isnt it?

Any ideas ?

Comment: I think that you should specify less meters: locManager.requestLocationUpdates(bestProvider, 15000, 5, locListener); (for example)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you register the location listener, you're requesting updates with a min time of 15 seconds and a minimum distance of 20 meters. Since you're inside an office, it's unlikely that you're able to get an accurate enough GPS fix to actually detect a move of 5-10 meters. Have you tried debugging outside? Similarly, if you enabled mock locations, send mock coordinates to the emulator to ensure your app acts as you expect when locations are updated.

Answer (score 1):

try with -

```
    locManager.requestLocationUpdates(bestProvider, 0, 0, locListener);
```